Get error:Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.setLayoutManager on a null object reference
I am trying to add values in Recyclerview to  show data

Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.setLayoutManager on a null object reference

  public void apiCallBackOverRideMethodObj(Response< Object > response, JSONObject objResponse, String method, int position, String success) throws JSONException, IOException {
        if (response != null) {
            JSONObject object = new JSONObject( new Gson().toJson( response.body() ) );
            System.out.println( "response : " + object );
            responsePojo = new Gson().fromJson( object.toString(), new TypeToken< ResponsePojo >() {
            }.getType() );
            if (responsePojo.getItemData() != null) {
                itemData.clear();
                itemData.addAll( responsePojo.getItemData() );
                for (int i = 0; i < itemData.size(); i++) {
                    itemlist.add( datalist.get( i ).getItemName() );
                    ArrayAdapter< String > adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>( MaterialDetails.this, R.layout.spinner_item, itemlist );
                    spinner.setAdapter( adapter );
                }
            }
        }
    }

I am facing error in below Recylerview Lines
      recyclerView = findViewById( R.id.recycler_view_data );
        materialAdapter = new MaterialAdapter( this, datalist );
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager( new LinearLayoutManager( MaterialDetails.this ) );
        recyclerView.setAdapter( materialAdapter );


recyclerView = findViewById( R.id.recycler_view_data );
        materialAdapter = new MaterialAdapter( this, datalist );
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager( new LinearLayoutManager( MaterialDetails.this ) );
        recyclerView.setAdapter( materialAdapter );

Call above code in onViewCreated() of fragment or onCreate() of an Activity.

i used onCreate() .

Then in that case findViewById( R.id.recycler_view_data ) is returning null. Check your id in xml file

Sure but id in XML  file is correct .
